# Value keeps overriding my old value in a session array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very simple random number generator. This number generator has a few options: you input a minimum and maximum number, form this number a random number will be generated. I store the maximum-minimum and generated number inside of a session to be used later while playing the game.

When we get redirected to the main page (the guess game) you have the option to guess the random number that is stored in the session from their one forth the game will give you feedback on how close you are etc.

My question boils down to this, an option of the game is to display all your previous guesses I had a basic idea of how I wanted to do this: I will store the current guess I did inside of an array this array will be linked to a session from which I can loop through all of the old guesses.

I have written a couple of functions to achieve this and it only stores the current guess overriding any number already stored in the array e.g. if my current guess is 6 this number will be stored inside the array, if I proceed to guess again for example 4 this number will be stored inside of the array but will override 6.

I hope my code examples will be more clear.

this function stores the old guesses inside of said array

```
public function Store_Old_Guesses_In_Session()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION["show_previous_guesses"])) {
        return false;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["Guess_Button"])) {
        return $_SESSION["old_guesses"] = $this->old_guesses = array(
            "Old_guesses" => $this->getCurrentGuess(),
        );
    }
    return false;
}
```

this function gets the current guess

```
public function getCurrentGuess()
{
    if (isset($this->current_guess)) {
        return $this->current_guess;
    }
    return false;
}
```

  -

```
namespace Store;


use Get_Number\Get_Numbers;

require_once "Current_Guesses.php";

class Store_Numbers extends Get_Numbers
{
    public array $old_guesses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if (isset($_SESSION["old_guesses"])) {
            $this->old_guesses = $_SESSION["old_guesses"];
        }
    }

    public function Store_Current_Number_In_Session()
    {
        if (empty($this->getCurrentNumber())) {
            return false;
        }
        return $_SESSION["current_number"] = $this->getCurrentNumber();
    }

    public function Store_Minimum_Number_In_Session()
    {
        if (empty($this->getMinimumNumber())) {
            return false;
        }
        return $_SESSION["minimum_number"] = $this->getMinimumNumber();
    }

    public function Store_Maximum_Number_In_Session()
    {
        if (empty($this->getMaximumNumber())) {
            return false;
        }
        return $_SESSION["maximum_number"] = $this->getMaximumNumber();
    }

    public function Store_Checkbox_Value_In_Session()
    {
        if (empty($_POST["debug_options"])) {
            return false;
        }
        return $_SESSION["debug_options"] = $_POST["debug_options"];
    }

    public function Store_show_previous_guesses_Checkbox_In_Session()
    {
        if (empty($_POST["show_previous_guesses"])) {
            return false;
        }
        return $_SESSION["show_previous_guesses"] = $_POST["show_previous_guesses"];
    }

    public function Store_Current_Number_Checkbox_Value_In_Session()
    {
        if (empty($_POST["current_number_checkbox"])) {
            return false;
        }
        return $_SESSION["current_number_checkbox"] = $_POST["current_number_checkbox"];
    }

    public function Store_Old_Guesses_In_Session()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["show_previous_guesses"])) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_POST["Guess_Button"])) {
            $this->old_guesses[] = $this->getCurrentGuess();
            $_SESSION['old_guesses'] = array_push($this->old_guesses, $this->getCurrentGuess());
            return $this->old_guesses;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a bunch of code examples should you need more

A few things you might need to know:

- PHP = 7.4.2
- The property `$old_guesses` is declared as an array like this `public
  array $old_guesses;`

Comment: You're overwriting the array instead of pushing onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push onto the array, not assign to it.

```
public function Store_Old_Guesses_In_Session()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION["show_previous_guesses"])) {
        return false;
    }
    if (isset($_POST["Guess_Button"])) {
        $this->old_guesses[] = $this->getCurrentGuess();
        $_SESSION['old_guesses'] = $this->old_guesses;
        return $this->old_guesses;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The constructor should initialize the variable from the session variable to make it persist and grow.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['old_guesses'])) {
    $_SESSION['old_guesses'] = array();
}

$this->old_guesses = $_SESSION['old_guesses'];
```

Comment: Hey, i tried applying your code example and nothing has been changed. The value is still being overwritten at each guess. I tried changing the $_SESSION["old_guesses"] = $this->old_guesses;. to this $_SESSION["old_guesses"] = array_push($this->old_guesses,$this->getCurrentGuess); but this gives me an error of invalid argument trying to loop through each guess

Comment: When you create the class object, do you fill in `$this->old_guesses` from the session variable?

Comment: Hmm, no i don't do that. `$this->old_guesses` is an empty array until it is being called in the function

Comment: But if you want to add a guess every time the script is called, you need to initialize the variable from the session. Do this in the class constructor.

Comment: So i initialized `$this->old_guesses` in the constructor using this `if (isset($_SESSION["old_guesses"])) {$this->old_guesses[] = $_SESSION["old_guesses"];}` and looping through it with this `foreach ($_SESSION["old_guesses"] as $old_guess) {echo "These are all your old guesses {$old_guess}";}` but it still gives me an invalid argument

Comment: Don't use `[]` there. The session variable should already be an array.

Comment: Remove the `[]` in the constructor gives me a typeError saying that an integer is used instead of a array

Comment: I don't understand why, since `$_SESSION['old_guesses']` is an array, not an integer.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how it should be done.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you again. But I am unable to figure this out, the code example you updated still overwrites the old value in the array instead of pushing into it. if i change the method to `array_push` the `$_SESSION["old_guesses"]` no longer acts as an array, which means i can no longer loop through it.

Comment: Edit the question and add the whole class definition at the end (don't remove any of the original code).

Comment: Added the whole class

Comment: `array_push()` doesn't return the array, it returns the new size of the array. You shouldn't assign the result to the session variable. Make your `Store_Old_Guesses_In_Session` like mine.